# Modify request params with custom authentication

Tags: python, python-requests

I've just upgraded my requests library to 2.3.0 (from 0.14.0), and my custom authentication is no longer working. The issue is that the custom authentication we use appends an API key and a timestamp to the request, so all of our helper methods don't need to do it.

```
class APIAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, request):
        api_secret = settings.API_SHARED_SECRET
        api_key = settings.API_KEY
        request.params.update(dict(
            api_key=api_key,
            timestamp=int(time.time()*1000)))
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
            api_secret,
            msg=unquote(request.full_url),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
            ).digest()).decode()
        request.headers['Authorization'] = "signature {0}".format(signature)
        return request
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'PreparedRequest' object has no attribute 'params'
```

Prepared request does not allow modification of the params dict, presumably because it has already been constructed.  Is there a simple way to update the params dict from our custom authentication that leaves any existing params intact? Or do I have to bite the bullet and add these two parameters for every request method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, a `PreparedRequest` is now passed in, and the URL query string is already set from the parameters.

However, the [`PreparedRequest.prepare_url()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_url) will let you *update* the URL with additional parameters:

```
class APIAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, request):
        api_secret = settings.API_SHARED_SECRET
        api_key = settings.API_KEY
        request.prepare_url(request.url, dict(
            api_key=api_key,
            timestamp=int(time.time()*1000)))
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
            api_secret,
            msg=unquote(request.full_url),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
            ).digest()).decode()
        request.headers['Authorization'] = "signature {0}".format(signature)
        return request
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> prepared = requests.Request(url='http://httpbin.org/get').prepare()
>>> prepared.url
'http://httpbin.org/get'
>>> prepared.prepare_url(prepared.url, {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 42})
>>> prepared.url
'http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar&spam=42'
>>> prepared.prepare_url(prepared.url, {'monty': 'python'})
>>> prepared.url
'http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar&spam=42&monty=python'
```

By passing in `prepared.url` the URL is updated to add the extra parameters. New parameters are always *additive*; if a new parameter has the same name as an already added parameter the old parameter is not removed.

Comment: Perfect. I was looking into that method, but didn't even think that existing params would be handled correctly. Hats off to Kenneth once again.